# Modal Validation with Javascript in laravel form

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup, laravel-8, show-hide

My code uses a modal for form display, and I want to make the modal unlock when validation is active.
but after i add some javascript function line, it still doesn't work.

```
My Modal
<div class="modal fade" id="passwordModal{{Auth::user()->id}}">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg-6">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="passwordModal">Update Password</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{ route('password.update') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="current_password" type="password" id="current_password" placeholder="Curent Password" class="form-control @error('current_password') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <span class="text-danger" id="current_passwordError"></span>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('current_password')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="New Password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <span class="text-danger" id="passwordError"></span>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('password')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="password_confirmation" type="password" id="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm New Password" class="form-control @error('password_confirmation') is-invalid @enderror">
                                <span class="text-danger" id="password_confirmationError"></span>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    @error('password_confirmation')
                                    {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my function js

```
<script>
function openModal() {
    $('#passwordModal{{Auth::user()->id}}').modal('show')
}

function storeData() {
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf - token"]').sttr('content');
    var current_password = $('#current_password').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var password_confirmation = $('#password_confirmation').val();

    $('#current_passwordError').addClass('d-none');
    $('#passwordError').addClass('d-none');
    $('#password_confirmationError').addClass('d-none');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('password.update') }}",
        data: {
            _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
            current_password: current_password,
            password: password,
            password_confirmation: password_confirmation,
        },

        success: function(data) {

        },

        error: function(data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            if ($.isEmptyObject(errors) == false) {
                $.each(errors.errors, function(key, value) {
                    var ErrorID = '#' + key + 'Error';
                    $(ErrorID).removeClass("d-none");
                    $(ErrorID).text(value)

                })
            }
        }
    });
}
```

is my script correct, or is there another way that is more effective.
before I could use ?
is my script correct, or is there another way that is more effective.

before i was able to handle this case in ci-3, but when i used that code in laravel it didn't work, that's why i tried another way and this is the result.

Comment: Im a little confused, what exactly is not working?

Comment: @KGG the modal dialog is still closed while validation is active. the modal dialog should remain open

Comment: Sounds like laravel is rendering something in a way you don't expect. Can you show the rendered code instead? Also, anything in the console?